# “2D table with headers” type container

Tags: c++

Consider the following data structure:

```
class Column {
    std::vector<Cell> cells; // in my case, usually 1 to 10 elements
    Header header; // some additional information
};

std::vector<Column> table;
// important: we now that all Columns have the same number of cells.

// you could also think of it as:
std::vector<std::pair<Header, std::vector<Cell>>> table_with_pairs;
```

Of course, this is fairly inefficient in terms of memory usage, and for certain operations (I am thinking of random access, or iterating over smaller parts of the table). Is there a ready-made container (probably non-STL) that could handle this “2D table with headers” better? Or a common practice? The goal would be a high-performance, easy-to-maintain and readable solution.

This problem seems related to the well-known “2D array” task but we have the additional header information. One solution I can think of is to store the headers in a std::vector parallel to a 2D array (pick your favourite solution) but that’s not easy to maintain, might have bad locality, and is against the principles of OOP. I’d prefer a memory layout similar to a `std::vector<std::pair<Header, std::array<Cell,n>>>` with `n` not known at compile time but constant. Determining the address of a cell (or header) would be nearly as trivial as in a 2D array but I thought I’d ask before coding my own solution.

[Edit] To clarify, I am not thinking about things like Excel sheets here. I could have called it “vector of objects that contain a vector and other data”.

Comment: *"Of course, this is fairly inefficient"* - How do you know?  What operations should this container be optimized for?  (e.g. insertion, deletion, row-wise iteration, column-wise iteration, random access, lookup via column name?)

Comment: Maybe rethink the direction here? If it were rows instead of columns, each row could be a struct. The header could be a separate list of strings. Like...  `class Table { vector<string> header; vector<data> rows; }` Inserting a deleting data would be fairly normal vector operations, as long as the number / type of columns is set.

Comment: @0x5453 Good point! I just edited the question, hope this makes it clearer.